# Is it okay to post questions on one Stack Exchange site and answers on another?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

My current status, as of the moment of this post is that on Stack Overflow I have 16 answers and 3 questions.  However on Arqade I haven't answered a single question, yet have asked 2, and will probably ask more.

Is it okay to ask questions on one site, without answering others (I have very few gaming matters I'm an expert on), if you answer questions on others?

I've seen many posts attacking people who only ask questions on certain Stack Exchange sites, and do not want to be attacked myself.

Comment: Go ahead. That's just fine

Comment: I've only answered questions on Arqade- And one of my Pokémon X/Y answers already has 14 upvotes, and I expect to post more well received answers in November when the next games come out. As long as your question quality is good, go for it. Arqade users appreciate good questions just as much as Stack Overflow users.

Comment: "I've seen many posts attacking people who only ask questions", I'm not sure exactly what you mean here but that shouldn't happen. As long as the questions are good, useful, and adhere to SE standards then they are still helping the site. And what Bart said

Comment: Great to know!  Thanks.  [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold) post seems to, if not attacking, challenge people who have asked far too many questions.

Comment: Note the key phrase there, "asking **meaningless, ridiculous** question after question" (emphasis mine), and that the post is from '09, when some question standards were looser and there was no systematic review of question quality.

Comment: Really more of a Meta SE question than a Meta SO question, no?

Comment: Hard to imagine that in most cases someone who needs to ask a lot of questions will also be able to provide good answers; and conversely, that someone who can provide many good answers will need to ask many questions.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus: What about an "intermediate" programmer?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Every site needs both people asking questions and answering. It is perfectly fine to be a question asker on one site, and an answerer on another.

Please do flag comments that attack someone for only asking questions, or only answering for that matter. As long as the questions and answers meet the quality standards of the site (on-topic, correct in so far possible, helpful, useful, etc.) your posts are welcome!